# Sum the values between two whole numbers?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that shows the tasks needed to be completed. Within this sheet there are the tasks and then sub tasks, with the tasks beig labeeled with a whole number and the sub tasks decimals. E.g. Task 42, sub task 42.1,42.2 etc.

I have trying to work out the workload of each task, but i dont want to create the formula for every task as there are many cells and the amount of sub tasks varies. I would like to be able to SUM the workload of the sub tasks to get the overall workload for the task. See picture.

[image]

Ideally, i would like the sum of workload sub-tasks 24, 25 and so on.

The location of the Sum would be within another sheet, next to the corresponding task it is calculating as well as the task number.

Is there excel basic function to use or would VBA be better

Comment: whether vba would be better depends on where the output goes.  Is it in its own column or do you want it in the grey box?

Comment: In its own column on another sheet, next to the corresponding task it is cAlculating

Comment: that is important info on how this would work, please [edit] the post and include that in the information.

Comment: Done. Thanks you for the tips on formatting questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUMIFS():

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">"&E1,A:A,"<"&E1+1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly! Could it be used with max to find the latest date etc. Where would the MAX function go

Comment: You question has no mention of MAX, so that would be a new question with its own post.